# What is this StopIteration error when trying to print function twice?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that selects multiple random lines from a text file that has different words on each line.

When I try to print `random_line` twice I get the error `StopIteration` on `line = aline`. How can I run the function multiple times without getting the error?

```
import random

def random_line(afile):
    line = next(afile)
    for num, aline in enumerate(afile):
      if random.randrange(num + 2): continue
      line = aline
    return line

f = open("english.txt", 'r')
print(random_line(f))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a StopIteration error due to the fact that the scanner has reached the end of the file - there are no more lines left to read!

You need to move it back to the start before trying to scan through the file again. This can be accomplished using `seek(0)` after your first function call.

```
f = open("english.txt", 'r')
print(random_line(f))
f.seek(0)
print(random_line(f))
f.close()
```